# Loading a model into partial view from within a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, loops, razor, partial-views

I want to display a partial view and populate it with the model Sale. Currently this is my (non-working) code:

Home view:

```
@foreach (Webshop.Models.Sale item in Model) {
    @Html.Partial("_Sale", (Webshop.Models.Sale) item)
}
```

Partial:

```
@model Webshop.Models.Sale

<div class="sale">
    <h5>@Html.ActionLink(item.Product.Name, "Details", "Product", new { id = item.ID }, null)</h5>
</div>
```

I get a compilation error saying item doesn't exist. If I name it model, it doesn't exist either.

- Is using a partial view actually the way to achieve what I want?
- What's the proper way of loading a model into a partial view from within my foreach loop?

Comment: your partial doesn't know what `item` is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your partial code. `item` should be `Model`:

```
@model Webshop.Models.Sale
<div class="sale">
    <h5>@Html.ActionLink(Model.Product.Name, "Details", "Product", new { id = Model.ID }, null)</h5>
</div>
```